# A question for using python "joblib.Parallel" function

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I want to repeat my function "Function_test" 100 times with Parallel for loop in python by using "joblib.Parallel", and all the results from 100 times for further analysis.

Here is my code:

```
import joblib

def FOMs_test(jj,image, Center_xy, BkgCenter_xy, roiSize_xy, Chnl,Resampling, Validation):

   # ... omit some code here

   _,dp[jj,ii], AUC[jj,ii], Pc[jj,ii] = Function_test (sig,bkg,channel,Noise,Resampling)
   print(jj)

return dp, AUC, Pc


dp, AUC, Pc = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=3)(joblib.delayed(FOMs_test)(jj,image, Center_xy, BkgCenter_xy, roiSize_xy, Chnl,Resampling, Validation) for jj in range(2))
```

After I run the above code, I got the following error message:

```
0
1
0
1
0
1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-81843d48c033> in <module>
----> 1 dp, AUC, Pc = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=3)(joblib.delayed(FOMs_test)(jj,image, Center_xy, BkgCenter_xy, roiSize_xy, Chnl,Resampling, Validation) for jj in range(2))

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that there are not enough values being returned from the `joblib.Parallel` call to unpack into the variables `dp`, `AUC`, and `Pc`.

This is because the `joblib.Parallel` call is currently only returning two sets of values, one for `jj`=0 and another for `jj`=1. To get the results of all 100 function calls, you need to adjust the range of the loop to `range(100)` instead of `range(2)`.

Also, you need to use a container to store the results from each iteration of the loop, such as a list, and then concatenate the results from all iterations into the final variables `dp`, `AUC`, and `Pc`.

Here's an updated version of the code that should work:

```
import joblib

def FOMs_test(jj, image, Center_xy, BkgCenter_xy, roiSize_xy, Chnl, Resampling, Validation):
   # ... omit some code here
   _, dp_jj, AUC_jj, Pc_jj = Function_test(sig, bkg, channel, Noise, Resampling)
   print(jj)
   return dp_jj, AUC_jj, Pc_jj


results = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=3)(
    joblib.delayed(FOMs_test)(jj, image, Center_xy, BkgCenter_xy, roiSize_xy, Chnl, Resampling, Validation)
    for jj in range(100)
)

# concatenate the results from all iterations
dp, AUC, Pc = map(lambda x: np.concatenate(x, axis=0), zip(*results))
```